# Providing default argument value in function definition

Tags: c, function-definition

This is where I am getting the error, also in the main, it is giving me a warning of implicit declaration of this bump function. Not sure why either. Edit: I just learned that C cannot have default arguments. Is there a way around this?

```
void bump(char*s, char c = 'o')
 {
   s.push_back(c);
 }

int main()
{
 char *s = "foo";
 printf("%s\n",s);

 bump(&s, '\0'); 
 printf("%s\n",s);

 bump(&s, 'x');
 printf("%s\n",s);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no default arguments for functions in C. Also, what are you expecting with `s.push_back(c);`?

Comment: also there is no `push_back` for `char*`

Comment: Your function signature should not have the default value, it should be `void bump(char *s, char c)`. Also, how do you expect to call the `push_back()` function from a char pointer?

Comment: `push_back()` in `C`?? This looks more like `C++` to me(except for the `printf()`)!

Comment: You need to return your C++ book, it's no good for learning C.

Comment: It's actually an assignment where my C professor gives us a C++ code and then I have to change it to C. This was as far as I got before I got completely stuck, I also couldn't put the whole code in here because it wouldn't let me post.

Comment: The program is just to print out "foo" then push_back(c) which is another 'o' and then 'x' so eventually print out "fooox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just learned that C cannot have default arguments. Is there a way around this?

Not really. See [Sourav Gosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48514974/841108) (which gives useful advice). What you could do is define a *different* function (with *another*, unique, name), e.g.

```
void bump_o(char*s) { bump(s, 'o'); }
```

and you could even define that function as `static inline` in some header file.

You might also use a macro:

```
#define BUMP_O(S) bump((S), 'o')
```

but that is generally poor taste.

Notice that **C and C++ are different languages**. The code you show us is not correct C (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

I recommend to compile your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), and to use a debugger (e.g. [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/))

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no default arguments in C. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1/P6, *Function definitions* (*emphasis mine*)

> If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in the declaration list shall
>   have at least one declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers from the
>   identifier list, and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared. An identifier
>   declared as a typedef name shall not be redeclared as a parameter. **The declarations in the
>   declaration list shall contain no storage-class specifier other than register and no
>   initializations.**

So, your function definition is a syntactical error. Compiler is complaining about the same.

That said, in the `bump()` function call,

- Looks like you need to pass a `char *`, not a `char **` (check the datatypes)
- The attempted operation is to modify a *string literal*. Even if you correct the first issue, you'll essentially invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to pass a modifiable memory, like, an array.